# I need a Git hook to sync MySql schema

Tags: mysql, git

One of the biggest problems i have today is that every time that i make a commit to git i get make the changes on the data base by hand. I don't want that the schema of the data base is always up to date.

I would like to be able have a pre commit hook that check the database schema and include it as part of the commit. Also that every time that I make a pull the data base gets updated.

Anyone has something like this already?

(I have a LAMP server, but I'm willing to install anything that helps me with this)

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/git/using-git-to-track-db-schema-changes-with-git-hook/